# как занести ссылку?

Tags: java

```
package com.javarush.test.level02.lesson02.task01;

/* Класс Person
В классе Person объяви следующие переменные: name типа String, age типа int, weight типа int, money типа int.
В методе main создай объект Person, занеси его ссылку в переменную person.
*/
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //напишите тут ваш код
    }

    public static class Person
    {
        //напишите тут ваш код
    }
}
```

Как занести ссылку?!

Answer (score 2):

```
Person person = new Person();
```

Здесь Вы создаете экземпляр класса `Person` и помещаете ссылку на него в объект `person`.

Answer (score 0):

**Задание:** в методе main создай объект Person, занеси его ссылку в переменную person.
**Решение:**

```
Person person = new Person();
```

**Полный вариант:**

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
    }

    public static class Person
    {
        //напишите тут ваш код
    }
}
```